# Genymotion not working on Mac

Tags: macos, virtualbox, genymotion

I *just* installed Genymotion this week on my mac and I installed the VirtualBox app as well.  I can get emulators to run periodically but often times they crash unexpectedly or won't open with the following error:

> Unable to connect to the virtual device. Genymotion will now close. 
>   Please check VirtualBox network configuration.
>
> For more information please refer to:
>   https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-nostart

Everything I've googled has not worked.  The virtual network seems fine.  I've tried deleted vm's, creating new ones, nothing seems to solve this problem.  It's going to the point where genymotion is unusable on my Mac.  Works fine on my windows machine.

BTW, the logs are endless messages that look like this:

```
10-09 20:46:10.912 E/eglCodecCommon(  119): TcpStream::connect() - connect() errno=111
10-09 20:46:10.912 E/        (  119): Failed to connect to host (TcpStream)!!!
10-09 20:46:10.912 E/EGL_genymotion(  119): Failed to establish connection with the host
```

Comment: Could you post how your virtual network adapters are set up in VirtualBox?  You should have two, one host-only adapter and one NAT.

Comment: @PaulRatazzi There isn't an adapter under NAT.  The host-only network is vboxnet0.  IPv4 Address is 192.168.56.1.  Mask: 255.255.255.0.  nothing under IPv6.  DHCP Server checked to enable server.  server address is 192.168.56.100.  mask same as other, lower bound 192.168.56.101 upper: 192.168.56.254

Comment: Hm. You should have two adapters configured. The host-only sounds like it's all set. Try enabling a second adapter, setting it to NAT and starting the machine. Make sure to start it from the Genymotion launcher, not directly from VB.

Comment: @PaulRatazzi I added a NAT adapter and it's still throwing the same error.  I even deleted everything and tried again.  I downloaded the update from VirtualBox as well.  Here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZ8DtD4QQCo&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: This is incredibly frustrating.  I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, removing the oracle virtual box, standing on one foot.  Still getting the same error.  I don't want to give up on Genymotion because I love it on my windows machine but I'm running out of ideas for the mac.  @PaulRatazzi any ideas?

Comment: Well, I don't have any experience with Genymotion on the Mac, just Ubuntu and Windows, and it's sounding more and more like this is a problem specific to the Mac. I'm wondering though - are you able to start the VM directly from VirtualBox instead of using the Genymotion launcher? This might help isolate the errors to one or  the other. Note that starting from VB will throw some errors (untracked pid in the VM console), but it should eventually start. If you can do this, then I would say the problem is with the launcher, not VirtualBox. That might help narrow this issue down a bit.

Comment: @PaulRatazzi yes, I tried that and it starts just fine from VirtualBox.  So it must be a problem with the GenyMotion launcher.  I also tried downgrading genymotion to the 2.2 version and am getting the same error.  I thought maybe it was an issue with permissions?  But running it with a sudo throws errors as well.

Comment: @ldeluca -- this is what I have in my network adapters. Adapter 1 (enabled):  attached to Host-only Adapter; name: vboxnet0; Adapter type: Paravirtualized Network; Promiscuous mode: deny; Cable Connected: yes. Adapter 2 (enabled): Attached to: NAT; Name: (empty); Adapter type: Paravirtualized network; Promiscuous mode: deny; Cable connected yes. I think your first is set up correctly, but double-check your NAT adapter.

You /shouldn't/ have to run it with sudo (I don't). That said, have you run a repair permissions in Disk Utility? Sometimes that will clear up permissions issues.

Comment: Probably doesn't make any difference, *but* what Mac are you on, and what version OS X?

Comment: @KerriShotts I'm on 10.9.5  Yes, I ran a repair permission in Disk Utility.